# List and run Excel worksheet macros using VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

I am trying to access macros stored in an excel workbook using vb6. I open a workbook containing a couple of sheets. Some of them have macros. What is the way to be able to list all the macros (with names) and give the user the cnahce to pick up one or more macros from the list and run them?

Similarly I want to be able to list buttons (command buttons placed on the sheet) not the toolbar buttons built in and eventually click it, again providing the users the name of the button (or best- its caption).

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code from [How to retrieve the names of macros from an Excel workbook by using Visual Basic 6.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315731) to load a list of macros from the worksheet (c:\abc.xls in the example) into a list box called List1:

```
Private Sub LoadMacrosList()
    ' Declare variables to access the Excel workbook.
    Dim objXLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objXLWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim objXLABC As Excel.Workbook

    ' Declare variables to access the macros in the workbook.
    Dim objProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim objComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim objCode As VBIDE.CodeModule

    ' Declare other miscellaneous variables.
    Dim iLine As Integer
    Dim sProcName As String
    Dim pk As vbext_ProcKind

    ' Open Excel, and open the workbook.
    Set objXLApp = New Excel.Application
    Set objXLWorkbooks = objXLApp.Workbooks    
    Set objXLABC = objXLWorkbooks.Open("C:\ABC.XLS")

    ' Empty the list box.
    List1.Clear

    ' Get the project details in the workbook.
    Set objProject = objXLABC.VBProject

    ' Iterate through each component in the project.
    For Each objComponent In objProject.VBComponents

        ' Find the code module for the project.
        Set objCode = objComponent.CodeModule

        ' Scan through the code module, looking for procedures.
        iLine = 1
        Do While iLine < objCode.CountOfLines
            sProcName = objCode.ProcOfLine(iLine, pk)
            If sProcName <> "" Then
                ' Found a procedure. Display its details, and then skip 
                ' to the end of the procedure.
                List1.AddItem objComponent.Name & vbTab & sProcName
                iLine = iLine + objCode.ProcCountLines(sProcName, pk)
            Else
                ' This line has no procedure, so go to the next line.
                iLine = iLine + 1
            End If
        Loop
        Set objCode = Nothing
        Set objComponent = Nothing
    Next

    Set objProject = Nothing

    ' Clean up and exit.
    objXLABC.Close
    objXLApp.Quit
End Sub
```

And here's some code to run one of the macros ([source](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?52175-How-to-run-Excel-Macro-from-VB6)):

```
Private Sub RunMacro(string macroName)
    'create and object (Excel SpreadSheet) 
    Dim oXL As Object 
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

    ' Open the workbook that contains the macro to run. 
    oXL.Workbooks.open "C:\ABC.XLS" 
    ' 
    'as object opens invisible, make visible if needed, if not omit 
    'the line oXL.visible=true 
    ' 
    oXL.Visible = True 
    ' 
    ' Run the macro. 
    oXL.Application.Run "abc.xls!" & macroName
    ' 
    ' Quit Microsoft Excel. 
    oXL.Quit 
    ' 
    ' Free the object from memory. 
    Set oXL = Nothing 
End Sub
```

With a little extra work on your part, you should be able to find command buttons as well. If you're looking for more than that, perhaps a more modern programming language would be more suitable.

Answer (score -1):

oXL.Application.Run "'abc.xls'!" & macroName
quote add

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).